# Get first and last array element where a ID is the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to calculate the time between the first and the last element in an array where they have the same sessionId

I have the following array:

```js
var arr = [
    {
      createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:30:46.367 +00:00',
      SessionID: 10,
      Name: 'Name1'
    },
    {
      createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:40:47.465 +00:00',
      SessionID: 10,
      Name: 'Name1'
    },
    {
      createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:45:48.596 +00:00',
      SessionID: 10,
      Name: 'Name1'
    },
    {
      createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:50:49.747 +00:00',
      SessionID: 11,
      Name: 'Name2'
    },
    {
      createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:52:50.814 +00:00',
      SessionID: 11,
      Name: 'Name2'
    },
    {
      createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:54:51.918 +00:00',
      SessionID: 11,
      Name: 'Name2'
    }
]
```

How do I get the first and the last element of each SessionId to calculate the passed time to map it like the following array?

```js
var newArr = [
  {
    Name: 'Name1',
    Time: 15
  },
  {
    Name: 'Name2',
    Time: 4
  }
]
```

I've tried that so far:

```js
let sessions = {}
a.forEach((item,index) => {
  sessions[item.SessionID] = sessions[item.SessionID] || [];
  sessions[item.SessionID].push(index);
})
```

and tried to splice the index's of them in between. But this doesn't work that well

Does anybody have an other idea?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: For example, you can try 

    var filteredArr = arr.filter(v => v.SessionID === 10) 

to get the items with same session id.

Then it will return new array for the filtered items

    filteredArr[0] // first element
    filteredArr[filteredArr.length - 1] // last element

Comment: What happens when there's only one session object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` and `Object.values` will simplify.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    createdAt: "2020-02-08 17:30:46.367 +00:00",
    SessionID: 10,
    Name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2020-02-08 17:40:47.465 +00:00",
    SessionID: 10,
    Name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2020-02-08 17:45:48.596 +00:00",
    SessionID: 10,
    Name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2020-02-08 17:50:49.747 +00:00",
    SessionID: 11,
    Name: "Name2"
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2020-02-08 17:52:50.814 +00:00",
    SessionID: 11,
    Name: "Name2"
  },
  {
    createdAt: "2020-02-08 17:54:51.918 +00:00",
    SessionID: 11,
    Name: "Name2"
  }
];

const updated = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { SessionID, createdAt } = curr;
    acc[SessionID] =
      SessionID in acc
        ? {
            ...acc[SessionID],
            Time:
              Math.floor((Date.parse(createdAt) -
              Date.parse(acc[SessionID].createdAt)) / (1000 * 60)),
          }
        : { ...curr };
    return acc;
  }, {})
).map(({Name, Time}) => ({ Name, Time }));

console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the min and max values of `createdAt` grouped by `SessionID` and get the delta of time in minutes.

```js
var array = [{ createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:30:46.367 +00:00', SessionID: 10, Name: 'Name1' }, { createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:40:47.465 +00:00', SessionID: 10, Name: 'Name1' }, { createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:45:48.596 +00:00', SessionID: 10, Name: 'Name1' }, { createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:50:49.747 +00:00', SessionID: 11, Name: 'Name2' }, { createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:52:50.814 +00:00', SessionID: 11, Name: 'Name2' }, { createdAt: '2020-02-08 17:54:51.918 +00:00', SessionID: 11, Name: 'Name2' }],
    result = Object
        .values(array.reduce((r, { createdAt, SessionID, Name }) => {
            if (!r[SessionID]) {
                r[SessionID] = { Name, min: createdAt, max: createdAt };
                return r;
            }
            if (r[SessionID].min > createdAt) r[SessionID].min = createdAt;
            if (r[SessionID].max < createdAt) r[SessionID].max = createdAt;
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(({ Name, min, max }) => ({ Name, Time: Math.floor((new Date(max) - new Date(min)) / 60000) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```